# LWC Event handler for event type with underscores

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

According to the [documentation on event dispatching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) event types should follow these rules:

- No uppercase letters
- No spaces
- Use underscores to separate words

When I attempt to use underscores in my event type I don't seem to be able to handle it.

Dispatcher:

```
<lightning-button label="Update" onclick={toggleEditAsset}></lightning-button>

toggleEditAsset = () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('toggle_edit_asset');
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Handler:

```
<c-asset-information asset={model.asset} edit-asset={editAsset} ontoggleeditasset={handleToggleEditAsset}></c-asset-information>

handleToggleEditAsset() {
    this.editAsset = !this.editAsset
    console.log('toggle');
}
```

This handler does not get called.

If I try to change `ontoggleeditasset` to `ontoggle_edit_asset` I get an error

> LWC1056: Invalid event name ontoggle_edit_asset. Event name can only contain lower-case alphabetic characterslwc

If I change the event to `toggleeditasset` everything works fine

What is the proper markup to handle an event with underscores?

Comment: Why don't you just leave it as const event = new CustomEvent('toggleeditasset'); That should work and you don't need to worry about anything else.

Comment: I wanted to follow best practices where it says `Use underscores to separate words`. I'm aware I can do that, but I was more curious about how to do it the way the documentation says to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle an event type `sampleevent` in HTML of parent, you should directly add prefix in attribute `onsampleevent`.

But, You cannot add event handler in HTML with underscores `_` as it will not compile.

However, you can do it through JS of parent component:

> **I would recommend not to create event-types with underscores as it may not even be supported from javascript in future releases (although currently it is able to handle)**

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.template.addEventListener('toggle_edit_asset', this.handleToggle);
}
handleToggle(e) {
    console.log('toggle_edit_asset handled');
}
```

[This is Playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/SA7JvMU9k/2/edit)

**This will work but you will be getting warning in the console as below:**

> [LWC warning]: Invalid event type "toggle_edit_asset" dispatched in
>   element . Event name should only contain lowercase
>   alphanumeric characters.

**IMPORTANT**

You need to add `bubbles:true` in event as you need to [Bubble an event up inside the containing component’s template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_propagation).

```
toggleEditAsset = () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('toggle_edit_asset', { bubbles: true });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: Can you help me debug this playground link? apparently dispatcher is not letting me fire event. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/SA7JvMU9k/1/edit

Comment: According to best practices, bubbling should not be used https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_best_practices

Comment: what we are doing is bubbles:true, composed:false - this will not become public API

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, you cannot have attribute with underscores in HTML, so you need to implement in JS. For this you need bubbles. Modified these in your playground link.

Comment: Right but according to the docs neither bubbling nor composed should be used. I see examples everywhere of people still using them though. It seems like the documentation is wrong for some of these event examples

Comment: @salesforce-sas can you share link, cant seem to find in any version, apprently it might have created a new version for you

Comment: Docs talk about only 2 scenarios - both true or both false. It recommends to use both bubbles and composed as true very carefully because it becomes component public API. Either of them true is totally fine

Comment: @PranayJaiswal.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/SA7JvMU9k/2/edit

Comment: @salesforce-sas Gotcha,,,+1  It fires .. but it shows a warning in JS console, do you think its a precursor for something that should not be used? `[LWC warning]: Invalid event type "toggle_edit_asset" dispatched in element <c-child>. Event name should only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters.`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal. Yes. Thats the reason I added in answer. Also it does not work from HTML. I hope someone from salesforce clarifies it.